# API integration in Codeigniter application

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, api, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to integrate API from `MyOperator`, in my `CRM` project, which is developed in `CodeIgniter`. For that they provide me some code, but when I tried to use that code in my application, it give me `JSON` data with

> 404 page not found error

Here is the code that they provided :

```
<?php                                                                                   

/**
 * @description : Library to access MyOperator Public API
 */
Class Myoperator {

    protected $developers_url = 'https://developers.myoperator.co/';
    protected $token = 'XXXXXXXXX';

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function run() {
        # request for Logs
        $url = $this->developers_url . 'search';
        $fields = array("token" => $this->token);
        $result = $this->_post_api($fields, $url);

        $this->log("result");
        $this->log($result);
    }

    private function _post_api(Array $fields, $url) {
        try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->log("url");
        $this->log($url);
        $this->log("fields");
        $this->log($fields);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($result)
            return $result;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private function log($message) {
        print_r($message);
        echo "\n";
    }

}


$Class = new Myoperator();
$Class->run();
```

This code gives me desired output if I run this code directly, but I'm confuse that where to use this code, which part is in controller and which part is in view in `CodeIgniter`. Any kind of help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: CORS, I think you need to look into CORS settings. If they didn't allow the CORS, you cannot call the api from cross-url (external-url).

Comment: @kishor10d They allow the CORS

Comment: Try to integrate codeigniter restful api library from here https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Comment: This is the response I received when executing your script:
`{"status":"error","message":"not authorized request","code":404}`

Comment: @Nguyen Thanh It uses POST request.

Comment: @GaneshAher What do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry, just said Thanks, and It uses POST request to get data.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a specialist of CodeIgniter, but after having a look to the documentation, and some links (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413940/create-simple-codeigniter-library) and [this](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html)) you can create your own library like this :

```
<?php                                                                                   

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * @description : Library to access MyOperator Public API
 */
Class Myoperator {

    protected $developers_url = 'https://developers.myoperator.co/';
    protected $token = 'XXXXXXXXX';

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function run() {
        # request for Logs
        $url = $this->developers_url . 'search';
        $fields = array("token" => $this->token);
        $result = $this->_post_api($fields, $url);

        $this->log("result");
        $this->log($result);
    }

    private function _post_api(Array $fields, $url) {
        try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->log("url");
        $this->log($url);
        $this->log("fields");
        $this->log($fields);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($result)
            return $result;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private function log($message) {
        print_r($message);
        echo "\n";
    }

}

?>
```

After that, you can get the library from the controller, like that :

```
<?php

class Operator extends CI_Controller 
{
   public function index()
   {
       $this->load->library('operator');  
       $this->operator->run();
   }
}

?>
```

**Edit** (Error handling)

```
<?php

class Operator extends CI_Controller 
{
   public function index()
   {
       try {
           $this->load->library('operator');  
           $this->operator->run();
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           var_dump($e->getMessage());
       }
   }
}

?>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for help, but it gives blank output.

Comment: Who you call the link, can you paste your PHP log error file ? I have updated my post to catch errors.

Comment: There is nothing in my log file and the whole screen is blank (white).

Comment: Sorry, but have you change the token to a right value ? What is you version of code igniter ? I will try on my local machine...

Comment: Try to replace this line : $this->load->library('operator'); by this one : $this->load->library('myoperator');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137999/discussion-between-mathieu-dormeval-and-ganesh-aher).

Answer (score 2):

> I run this code directly, but I'm confuse that where to use this code, which part is in controller and which part is in view in CodeIgniter.

It sounds like a quick primer on the structure of a CodeIgniter application is in order.  A default CI 3.1.3 release has this structure:

```
.
├── application/
├── composer.json
├── contributing.md
├── index.php
├── license.txt
├── readme.rst
├── system/
└── user_guide/
```

Your application, ***including your supplied library***, will reside inside the `application` directory.  In your case, the "Myoperator" library should be placed in **`application/libraries`**.  Your controller will reside in `application/controllers` and views in `application/views`.

In your final `Myoperator.php` file, you'll need to remove the last two lines that you have in your example.  Those will be replaced by their equivalents in your controller.

***In your controller***, you simply need to load the library like this:

```
$this->load->library('myoperator');
```

Then invoke the library like this:

```
$this->myoperator->run();
```

This is the CodeIgniter equivalent of those last 2 lines, `$Class = new Myoperator();` and `$Class->run();`

Answer (score 1):

In case they have given any library then you use that by including that library in your controller file then directly call their function.
If they have provided you a code then you have to create your own api file to call their url .Just code paste the code into the web/application/libraries/Operator.php(assuming the name of library).

Operator.php

```
<?php                                                                                   

/**
 * @description : Library to access MyOperator Public API
 */
Class Myoperator {

    protected $developers_url = 'https://developers.myoperator.co/';
    protected $token = 'XXXXXXXXX';

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function run() {
        # request for Logs
        $url = $this->developers_url . 'search';
        $fields = array("token" => $this->token);
        $result = $this->_post_api($fields, $url);

        $this->log("result");
        $this->log($result);
    }

    private function _post_api(Array $fields, $url) {
        try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->log("url");
        $this->log($url);
        $this->log("fields");
        $this->log($fields);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($result)
            return $result;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private function log($message) {
        print_r($message);
        echo "\n";
    }

}
```

Then in your custom controller include the api and extend the controller with it.And then call the function of that api automatically.

```
require('application/libraries/Operator.php');
class Users extends Operator
{
    public function __Construct()
    {
       $this->run(); /*You can call the function directly using $this*/
    }
}
```

I don't know the working of the api but the method you can try this.I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own library in the following direction **Application/libraries/** 
And paste the following code:

```
 <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); Class Myoperator {

protected $developers_url = 'https://developers.myoperator.co/';
protected $token = 'XXXXXXXXX';

function __construct() {

}

public function run() {
    # request for Logs
    $url = $this->developers_url . 'search';
    $fields = array("token" => $this->token);
    $result = $this->_post_api($fields, $url);

    $this->log("result");
    $this->log($result);
}

private function _post_api(Array $fields, $url) {
    try {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->log("url");
    $this->log($url);
    $this->log("fields");
    $this->log($fields);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($result)
        return $result;
    else
        return false;
}

private function log($message) {
    print_r($message);
    echo "\n";
} } ?>
```

After that, you can use the library in the controller, like that :

```
  public function index() {
   $this->load->library('operator');  
   $this->operator->run();}
```

Error handling:

```
public function index(){
   try {
       $this->load->library('operator');  
       $this->operator->run();
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       var_dump($e->getMessage());
   }}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, I do that already. But now the challenge for me is that how to get values from json file.

Comment: In the library file inside run function just return  json value like this: 
return json_encode($result);

Answer (score 0):

By using this code I got my answer, Actually I forgot to include my `Admin_controller` in my `Controller` class.

My library file :

```
<?php                                                                                   

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

//require APPPATH. 'core/Admin_controller.php';

/**
 * @description : Library to access MyOperator Public API
 */
Class MY_Operator {

    protected $developers_url = 'https://developers.myoperator.co/';
    protected $token = 'XXXXXXXXXX';

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function run() {
        # request for Logs
        $url = $this->developers_url . 'search';
        $fields = array("token" => $this->token);
        $result = $this->_post_api($fields, $url);

        $this->log("result");
        $this->log($result);
    }

    private function _post_api(Array $fields, $url) {
        try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->log("url");
        $this->log($url);
        $this->log("fields");
        $this->log($fields);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($result)
            return $result;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private function log($message) {
        print_r($message);
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

This id Controller code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH. 'core/Admin_controller.php';
//Added above line to get output
class Myoperator extends Admin_controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('MY_Operator');
        //$this->load->model('home_model');
    }

    public function index()
   {
       try {

            $this->my_operator->run();
       } catch (Exception $e) {
           var_dump($e->getMessage());
       }

       $this->load->view('admin/myoperator/view');
   }
}
```

**Edited :**

This is the code that gives me output, in json format, which is I'm looking for.

Comment: Where are you making the `json_decode()` call?  I see in the library file where you are referencing `$result`.  Is this where you are trying the `json_decode()`?  If so, you should return `$result` (or `json_decode($result)`) from the `run()` method in your library, then assign that return value in the `index` method of your controller to `$data['m']`.  You then can pass that to the view by `$this->load->view('admin/myoperator/view', $data);`

Comment: Actually, above code gives me the output. Sorry that I'm not update my answer.

Comment: It's not really cool to unaccept the answer (mostely for the bounty), I clearly put you on the right track !